# Mongo refuses to utilize all fields from compound index

Tags: mongodb, indexing, compound-index

I have a large database and a number of compound indexes. The problem is, mongo does not use all fields from index for query, it only uses 2 fields out of 4, even though all 4 fields are in the compound index. Or it uses 3-field compound index instead of 4-field.

Here is my schema (there are other fields in data and meta, but they are not used in this query):

```
{
    store_id: {type: String},
    data: {
        id: {type: Number},
    },
    meta: {
        is_published: {type: Boolean},
        lowercase_sku: {type: String}
    }
}
```

I have these indexes:

```
db.products.createIndex({'store_id':1,'meta.is_published':1,'data.id':1})
db.products.createIndex({'store_id':1,'meta.is_published':1,'data.id':1,'meta.lowercase_sku':1})
```

Here is my query:

```
db.products.find({
    'store_id': 'my_domain.com',
    'meta.lowercase_sku': 'go-a83-3034/8+4',
    'meta.is_published': true, 
    'data.id': {'$ne': 7801040323}
}).explain('executionStats')
```

And here is what I get from explain:

```
{
    "queryPlanner" : {
        "plannerVersion" : 1,
        "namespace" : "my_database.products",
        "indexFilterSet" : false,
        "parsedQuery" : {
            "$and" : [
                {
                    "meta.is_published" : {
                        "$eq" : true
                    }
                },
                {
                    "meta.lowercase_sku" : {
                        "$eq" : "go-a83-3034/8+4"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "store_id" : {
                        "$eq" : "my_domain.com"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "$not" : {
                        "data.id" : {
                            "$eq" : 7801040323
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        "winningPlan" : {
            "stage" : "FETCH",
            "filter" : {
                "meta.lowercase_sku" : {
                    "$eq" : "go-a83-3034/8+4"
                }
            },
            "inputStage" : {
                "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                "keyPattern" : {
                    "store_id" : 1,
                    "meta.is_published" : 1,
                    "data.id" : 1
                },
                "indexName" : "store_id_1_meta.is_published_1_data.id_1",
                "isMultiKey" : false,
                "isUnique" : false,
                "isSparse" : false,
                "isPartial" : false,
                "indexVersion" : 1,
                "direction" : "forward",
                "indexBounds" : {
                    "store_id" : [
                        "[\"my_domain.com\", \"my_domain.com\"]"
                    ],
                    "meta.is_published" : [
                        "[true, true]"
                    ],
                    "data.id" : [
                        "[MinKey, 7801040323.0)",
                        "(7801040323.0, MaxKey]"
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        "rejectedPlans" : [
            {
                "stage" : "FETCH",
                "filter" : {
                    "$and" : [
                        {
                            "$not" : {
                                "data.id" : {
                                    "$eq" : 7801040323
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "meta.lowercase_sku" : {
                                "$eq" : "go-a83-3034/8+4"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "inputStage" : {
                    "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                    "keyPattern" : {
                        "store_id" : 1,
                        "meta.is_published" : 1,
                        "data.id" : 1,
                        "meta.lowercase_sku" : 1
                    },
                    "indexName" : "store_id_1_meta.is_published_1_data.id_1_meta.lowercase_sku_1",
                    "isMultiKey" : true,
                    "isUnique" : false,
                    "isSparse" : false,
                    "isPartial" : false,
                    "indexVersion" : 1,
                    "direction" : "forward",
                    "indexBounds" : {
                        "store_id" : [
                            "[\"my_domain.com\", \"my_domain.com\"]"
                        ],
                        "meta.is_published" : [
                            "[true, true]"
                        ],
                        "data.id" : [
                            "[MinKey, 7801040323.0)",
                            "(7801040323.0, MaxKey]"
                        ],
                        "meta.lowercase_sku" : [
                            "[MinKey, MaxKey]"
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    "executionStats" : {
        "executionSuccess" : true,
        "nReturned" : 1,
        "executionTimeMillis" : 4590,
        "totalKeysExamined" : 28527,
        "totalDocsExamined" : 28525,
        "executionStages" : {
            "stage" : "FETCH",
            "filter" : {
                "meta.lowercase_sku" : {
                    "$eq" : "go-a83-3034/8+4"
                }
            },
            "nReturned" : 1,
            "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 130,
            "works" : 28528,
            "advanced" : 1,
            "needTime" : 28525,
            "needYield" : 0,
            "saveState" : 5351,
            "restoreState" : 5351,
            "isEOF" : 1,
            "invalidates" : 0,
            "docsExamined" : 28525,
            "alreadyHasObj" : 0,
            "inputStage" : {
                "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                "nReturned" : 28525,
                "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 70,
                "works" : 28527,
                "advanced" : 28525,
                "needTime" : 1,
                "needYield" : 0,
                "saveState" : 5351,
                "restoreState" : 5351,
                "isEOF" : 1,
                "invalidates" : 0,
                "keyPattern" : {
                    "store_id" : 1,
                    "meta.is_published" : 1,
                    "data.id" : 1
                },
                "indexName" : "store_id_1_meta.is_published_1_data.id_1",
                "isMultiKey" : false,
                "isUnique" : false,
                "isSparse" : false,
                "isPartial" : false,
                "indexVersion" : 1,
                "direction" : "forward",
                "indexBounds" : {
                    "store_id" : [
                        "[\"my_domain.com\", \"my_domain.com\"]"
                    ],
                    "meta.is_published" : [
                        "[true, true]"
                    ],
                    "data.id" : [
                        "[MinKey, 7801040323.0)",
                        "(7801040323.0, MaxKey]"
                    ]
                },
                "keysExamined" : 28527,
                "dupsTested" : 0,
                "dupsDropped" : 0,
                "seenInvalidated" : 0
            }
        }
    },
    "serverInfo" : {
        "version" : "3.2.18",
        "gitVersion" : "4c1bae566c0c00f996a2feb16febf84936ecaf6f"
    },
    "ok" : 1
}
```

As you can see, for some reason mongo does not uses 4-field index, and even if I hint at the index, it only uses two first fields ("store_id" and "meta.is_published"). It tends to choose 3-fields index which only covers 3 fields ("store_id", "meta.is_published" and "data.id"), which kinda makes sense, provided that from 4-field index only 2 fields are used. But why?

Can someone explain this to me and maybe hint how can I get the query to work faster?

The database is big (about 11 G) and it was migrated recently (imported with indexes), if that helps. However, indexes in question were created AFTER the import.

UPD (2): I also created a test collection of documents with the same schema and indexes. And the same query indeed uses the index properly. So I tend to think there is some kind of problem with index size or value types. But I still can't pinpont it.

Any help or insights on this I appericate greatly.

---

Below is query with a hint to 4-field index and the result for you reference.

```
db.products.find({
    'store_id': 'my_domain.com',
    'meta.lowercase_sku': 'go-a83-3034/8+4',
    'meta.is_published': true, 
    'data.id': {'$ne': 7801040323}
}).hint('store_id_1_meta.is_published_1_data.id_1_meta.lowercase_sku_1').explain('executionStats')
```

Result:

```
{
    "queryPlanner" : {
        "plannerVersion" : 1,
        "namespace" : "sharp_production.products",
        "indexFilterSet" : false,
        "parsedQuery" : {
            "$and" : [
                {
                    "meta.is_published" : {
                        "$eq" : true
                    }
                },
                {
                    "meta.lowercase_sku" : {
                        "$eq" : "go-a83-3034/8+4"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "store_id" : {
                        "$eq" : "my_domain.com"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "$not" : {
                        "data.id" : {
                            "$eq" : 7801040323
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        "winningPlan" : {
            "stage" : "FETCH",
            "filter" : {
                "$and" : [
                    {
                        "$not" : {
                            "data.id" : {
                                "$eq" : 7801040323
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "meta.lowercase_sku" : {
                            "$eq" : "go-a83-3034/8+4"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            "inputStage" : {
                "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                "keyPattern" : {
                    "store_id" : 1,
                    "meta.is_published" : 1,
                    "data.id" : 1,
                    "meta.lowercase_sku" : 1
                },
                "indexName" : "store_id_1_meta.is_published_1_data.id_1_meta.lowercase_sku_1",
                "isMultiKey" : true,
                "isUnique" : false,
                "isSparse" : false,
                "isPartial" : false,
                "indexVersion" : 1,
                "direction" : "forward",
                "indexBounds" : {
                    "store_id" : [
                        "[\"my_domain.com\", \"my_domain.com\"]"
                    ],
                    "meta.is_published" : [
                        "[true, true]"
                    ],
                    "data.id" : [
                        "[MinKey, 7801040323.0)",
                        "(7801040323.0, MaxKey]"
                    ],
                    "meta.lowercase_sku" : [
                        "[MinKey, MaxKey]"
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        "rejectedPlans" : [ ]
    },
    "executionStats" : {
        "executionSuccess" : true,
        "nReturned" : 1,
        "executionTimeMillis" : 213,
        "totalKeysExamined" : 28630,
        "totalDocsExamined" : 28525,
        "executionStages" : {
            "stage" : "FETCH",
            "filter" : {
                "$and" : [
                    {
                        "$not" : {
                            "data.id" : {
                                "$eq" : 7801040323
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "meta.lowercase_sku" : {
                            "$eq" : "go-a83-3034/8+4"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            "nReturned" : 1,
            "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 210,
            "works" : 28630,
            "advanced" : 1,
            "needTime" : 28628,
            "needYield" : 0,
            "saveState" : 223,
            "restoreState" : 223,
            "isEOF" : 1,
            "invalidates" : 0,
            "docsExamined" : 28525,
            "alreadyHasObj" : 0,
            "inputStage" : {
                "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                "nReturned" : 28525,
                "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 110,
                "works" : 28630,
                "advanced" : 28525,
                "needTime" : 104,
                "needYield" : 0,
                "saveState" : 223,
                "restoreState" : 223,
                "isEOF" : 1,
                "invalidates" : 0,
                "keyPattern" : {
                    "store_id" : 1,
                    "meta.is_published" : 1,
                    "data.id" : 1,
                    "meta.lowercase_sku" : 1
                },
                "indexName" : "store_id_1_meta.is_published_1_data.id_1_meta.lowercase_sku_1",
                "isMultiKey" : true,
                "isUnique" : false,
                "isSparse" : false,
                "isPartial" : false,
                "indexVersion" : 1,
                "direction" : "forward",
                "indexBounds" : {
                    "store_id" : [
                        "[\"my_domain.com\", \"my_domain.com\"]"
                    ],
                    "meta.is_published" : [
                        "[true, true]"
                    ],
                    "data.id" : [
                        "[MinKey, 7801040323.0)",
                        "(7801040323.0, MaxKey]"
                    ],
                    "meta.lowercase_sku" : [
                        "[MinKey, MaxKey]"
                    ]
                },
                "keysExamined" : 28630,
                "dupsTested" : 28628,
                "dupsDropped" : 103,
                "seenInvalidated" : 0
            }
        }
    },
    "serverInfo" : {
        "version" : "3.2.18",
        "gitVersion" : "4c1bae566c0c00f996a2feb16febf84936ecaf6f"
    },
    "ok" : 1
}
```

---

UPDATE (1)

---

Okay, apparently "$ne" operator may spoil the index, like @JohnnyHK said. So I created another one like this:

```
db.products.createIndex({'store_id':1,'meta.is_published':1,'meta.lowercase_sku':1})
```

...and tried to use it for my query after removing "$ne" (it's just one document, does not really change anything):

```
db.products.find({
    'store_id': 'my_domain.com',
    'meta.is_published': true,
    'meta.lowercase_sku': 'go-a83-3034/8+4',
}).hint('store_id_1_meta.is_published_1_meta.lowercase_sku_1').explain('executionStats')
```

But here is what I've got this time:

```
{
    "queryPlanner" : {
        "plannerVersion" : 1,
        "namespace" : "sharp_production.products",
        "indexFilterSet" : false,
        "parsedQuery" : {
            "$and" : [
                {
                    "meta.is_published" : {
                        "$eq" : true
                    }
                },
                {
                    "meta.lowercase_sku" : {
                        "$eq" : "go-a83-3034/8+4"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "store_id" : {
                        "$eq" : "my_domain.com"
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        "winningPlan" : {
            "stage" : "FETCH",
            "filter" : {
                "meta.lowercase_sku" : {
                    "$eq" : "go-a83-3034/8+4"
                }
            },
            "inputStage" : {
                "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                "keyPattern" : {
                    "store_id" : 1,
                    "meta.is_published" : 1,
                    "meta.lowercase_sku" : 1
                },
                "indexName" : "store_id_1_meta.is_published_1_meta.lowercase_sku_1",
                "isMultiKey" : true,
                "isUnique" : false,
                "isSparse" : false,
                "isPartial" : false,
                "indexVersion" : 1,
                "direction" : "forward",
                "indexBounds" : {
                    "store_id" : [
                        "[\"my_domain.com\", \"my_domain.com\"]"
                    ],
                    "meta.is_published" : [
                        "[true, true]"
                    ],
                    "meta.lowercase_sku" : [
                        "[MinKey, MaxKey]"
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        "rejectedPlans" : [ ]
    },
    "executionStats" : {
        "executionSuccess" : true,
        "nReturned" : 1,
        "executionTimeMillis" : 136,
        "totalKeysExamined" : 28629,
        "totalDocsExamined" : 28526,
        "executionStages" : {
            "stage" : "FETCH",
            "filter" : {
                "meta.lowercase_sku" : {
                    "$eq" : "go-a83-3034/8+4"
                }
            },
            "nReturned" : 1,
            "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 120,
            "works" : 28630,
            "advanced" : 1,
            "needTime" : 28628,
            "needYield" : 0,
            "saveState" : 223,
            "restoreState" : 223,
            "isEOF" : 1,
            "invalidates" : 0,
            "docsExamined" : 28526,
            "alreadyHasObj" : 0,
            "inputStage" : {
                "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                "nReturned" : 28526,
                "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 30,
                "works" : 28630,
                "advanced" : 28526,
                "needTime" : 103,
                "needYield" : 0,
                "saveState" : 223,
                "restoreState" : 223,
                "isEOF" : 1,
                "invalidates" : 0,
                "keyPattern" : {
                    "store_id" : 1,
                    "meta.is_published" : 1,
                    "meta.lowercase_sku" : 1
                },
                "indexName" : "store_id_1_meta.is_published_1_meta.lowercase_sku_1",
                "isMultiKey" : true,
                "isUnique" : false,
                "isSparse" : false,
                "isPartial" : false,
                "indexVersion" : 1,
                "direction" : "forward",
                "indexBounds" : {
                    "store_id" : [
                        "[\"my_domain.com\", \"my_domain.com\"]"
                    ],
                    "meta.is_published" : [
                        "[true, true]"
                    ],
                    "meta.lowercase_sku" : [
                        "[MinKey, MaxKey]"
                    ]
                },
                "keysExamined" : 28629,
                "dupsTested" : 28629,
                "dupsDropped" : 103,
                "seenInvalidated" : 0
            }
        }
    },
    "serverInfo" : {
        "version" : "3.2.18",
        "gitVersion" : "4c1bae566c0c00f996a2feb16febf84936ecaf6f"
    },
    "ok" : 1
}
```

...Still keeps the "meta.lowercase_sku" condition for FETCH stage, even though it's right there in the index. Any more ideas?

Comment: From the docs: `The inequality operator $ne is not very selective since it often matches a large portion of the index. As a result, in many cases, a $ne query with an index may perform no better than a $ne query that must scan all documents in a collection.`

Comment: Oh, so then I may benefit if I create index like this:

    db.products.createIndex({'store_id':1,'meta.is_published':1,'meta.lowercase_sku':1})

...and maybe remove the $ne condition as well. Thank you, I'll give it a try and report here.

Comment: @JohnnyHK , I updated the post with the results, please have a look. The results are... interesting. ;)

Comment: I've created a test collection with a dozen of documents and the same indexes. When the same query runs on this collection, all 4 fields are resolved via index (there is nothing on FETCH stage and execution stats shows totalDocsExamined: 1). I believe there may be some problem with mongo limits (the database is big as you know), but I can't find anything appropriate in the docs. What did I miss?

Answer (score 4):

This is due to how the query planner selects the index to use.

The gist of the issue is that you have more than one indexes which can satisfy the query. Let's say you have two index with identical prefix:

```
db.test.createIndex({a:1, b:1})
```

and

```
db.test.createIndex({a:1, b:1, c:1})
```

Now if you do:

```
db.test.find({a:1, b:1})
```

How does MongoDB knows which index can satisfy that query? Depending on the layout in disk (among many things), one index could be faster than the other.

So first it will rank the plans using this formula:

```
score = baseScore + productivity + tieBreakers
```

where currently in MongoDB 3.6.3, `baseScore = 1`, `productivity` depends on how much work needed for the plan to return as much result as possible, and `tieBreakers` depends on whether the index needs to `FETCH`, having no `SORT` stage, or having index intersection.

If two plans gave identical scores (as is the two plans above), then it puts them in a race to get 101 results faster. The winning plan will get cached, and the plan gets executed. As you can imagine, this could be non-deterministic, and also wasting the server's time. It's best if the server can just pick an index based on the scoring system instead.

The best way to index a collection is to remove non-essential indexes to ensure that MongoDB can immediately pick an index.

**Note**: if you're interested in the gritty details, you can:

- Log the query planning method by using `db.setLogLevel(5,'query')` and see the process printed in the `mongod` logs.
- `db.collection.getPlanCache().clear()` to clear the plan cache for a collection.
- Examine [the plan ranker source code](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/v3.6/src/mongo/db/query/plan_ranker.cpp).
- Check out the blog post [Optimizing MongoDB Compound Indexes](https://emptysqua.re/blog/optimizing-mongodb-compound-indexes/).

Comment: Thank you for your response. As you can see, the second index should cover my query completely, but it is not used for all fields even when I directly point at it (please see the second query output). So, as much as I'd wanted to blame query planner, I can't really.

Comment: My later updates indicate that the index should indeed work like you said, but for some reason it doesn't work on my collection. Maybe it is just too big? There are millions of documents there, but I didn't believe it could be a problem till now.

Comment: The `explain()` output shows that you have `"isMultiKey" : true`, which I suspect the field `meta.lowercase_sku` in some documents contains an array. Note the line `"meta.lowercase_sku" : ["[MinKey, MaxKey]"]`, which means that MongoDB cannot use the index for that field. The behaviour is slightly different for multikey indexes, but this is a different topic. If you remove the array field and recreate the index, MongoDB can use the index like you think.

Comment: That's definitely worth a try, thank you very much for the idea! I will check if I have some arrays there and maybe this will do the trick. I'll post here when I have the results. Thanks again!

Comment: I'm still checking for other possibilities, but the initial idea of meta.lowercase_sku having an array value somewhere has not been confirmed. However, not all of the values have string type. In some documents there isn't such field at all. Can this be an issue?

Comment: MongoDB will only set an index to be multikey when it found an array. If the document with the array was deleted, the multikey flag will not be reset. Try to recreate the index if this is the case.

Comment: Understood, thanks again for your help! I will try to recreate the index, though it will have to wait until the maintenance window.